# How can I hide filename in the url bar?

Tags: javascript

localhost/System/CAPSTONE/viewresult.php

How can I hide the "viewresult.php" filename in the URL bar?

Comment: Can you elobrate your question, 
what do you mean by searching ?
what is meaning of hiding, means hide from urlbar or what ?

Comment: Well, one method would be to change it's filename to index.php and link to the folder instead. Not really an answer, just workaround. More importantly, why? What's bad about "viewresult.php"? This seems like a classic example of asking X to solve Y instead of asking how to solve Y.

Answer (score 0):

Either rename viewresult.php to index.php or use .htaccess to make viewresult.php the default index file.

Add this in .htaccess file and place the .htaccess file in your website root folder.

```
DirectoryIndex viewresult.php
```

After that you can call it like localhost/System/CAPSTONE/

Answer (score 0):

there no way to hide the filename using htaccess, but using some php code in index file will do this..

```
$url=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $a= explode("/",$url);
 if($a[n]!='viewresult.php')
    {
            // your page content 

    }
        else
        {
               // your index page content
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice make use of jquery and you can easily do it. Otherwise also other way to do is to make use of iframes or Ajax. Load every new file in iframe after 1st page. Or load via ajax.